# TSQL with Group By Count and Rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, dense-rank

Let's say I have the following:

```
DECLARE @Name TABLE (Name VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @Name VALUES ('bob'),('bob'),('john'),('john'),('mark'),('mark'),('mark'),('lisa');

SELECT  Name,
COUNT(Name) AS TOTALS
FROM @Name
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY TOTALS DESC;
```

How can I also use Rank() or Dense_Rank() to get the rankings based on the counts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a rank column, you can use it with `group by`:

```
SELECT n.Name, COUNT(*) as TOTALS,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as Total_Rank
FROM @Name n
GROUP BY n.Name
ORDER BY TOTALS DESC;
```

Comment: but since mark has 3, the most out of all of them, how I show in Total_Rank him as 1?

Comment: @ACsteel Just reverse the order -- `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
    , RANK() OVER(ORDER BY totals DESC) AS Rank 
FROM
(
    SELECT  Name,
    COUNT(Name) AS TOTALS
    FROM @Name
    GROUP BY Name
) a
```